# GCMRegistrar cannot be resolved

Tags: android, import

I'm trying to implement Push Notification. I have a problem with `import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar` it cannot be resolved.

I did install `Google Play Services` and add `google-play-services_lib` to my projects folder.

But the problem remains. I tried to find `gcm.jar` as I saw solutions that worked for others, but I don't have this .jar.

Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: First of all download `Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library`. it's seems like u r missing **gcm.jar** file. you'll find this .jar into this path `D:\....\android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-client\libs` and add into your libs. that's it

Comment: After this path \google\ I don't have any folder \gcm. There are two folders google_play_services and usb_driver.

Comment: First of all download `Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library`. for this goto `Android SDK Manager->Extras->Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library` check and install it

Comment: The reason I didn't install it is  because this library is Obsolete and no longer supported. In documentation is written that it is been moved to Google Play Services. However it seems that it's not , since I can't see it. Will let you know, if it will work.

Comment: You have to upgrade your SDK Tools to latest version and also Platform-tools to latest version  before the `Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library` will appear in the `Extras` folder.

Comment: It did fix the problem, but there is still warning about obsolete. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all download `Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library`. For this goto `Android SDK Manager->Extras->Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library` check and install it.

See the below image:
[image]

Now, after downloading this libary you'll see `gcm` folder is available into path `D:\.....\android-sdk\extras\google`

Now You'll find `gcm.jar` into path `D:\....\android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-client\libs`.

Now, add this `gcm.jar` file into your project

Answer (score 5):

**GCMRegistrar** GCM API is deprecated.It is recommended to refer updated documentation on [Google developer Site](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging)

Answer (score 1):

Our Google overlords have decried that gcm.jar is deprecated as of Summer 2013 so whatever example code you're working off that requires GCMRegistrar.java is a bit outdated. Of course, just adding gcm.jar works well as stated in the other answers.

If you want to follow Google's commands for whatever reason, CommonsWare has an updated GCM example project that basically just copies the needed classes from gcm.jar and renames them with a 'compat' suffix:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient2/src/com/commonsware/android/gcm/client