# Android GCM is not importing properly

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I have a project in eclipse that I convert into Android Studio.In eclipse GCM is working perfectly.But after conversion to android studio **"com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;"** not properly importing

I added **"compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'"** in dependency.

and properly clean and sync the project, But still it is not importing the GCM package.

I dint get the idea why this happend, can any well please tell me where am wrong

**build.gradel**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.radiomango.app"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 24
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
dependencies {

compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar')
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
}
```

Comment: can you change compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' to compileSdkVersion '24' and try

Comment: I tried , but still the same problem @Nisarg

Comment: Have you already downloaded [Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575794/gcmregistrar-cannot-be-resolved)? Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575794/gcmregistrar-cannot-be-resolved), it might be of help.